# Firebase sendSignInLinkToEmail not working for some emails

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

this is my code:

I am using firebase signInlink to sign in users to my app who haven't set up passwords, like so:

```
 firebase
          .auth()
          .sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, {
            url: redirectUrl,
            handleCodeInApp: true,
          })
```

I am getting the emails for outlook.com / gmail account, but some users complain they don't get these emails - I tried a outlookt 365 accounr from godaddy in another domain and it gets most firebase emails (password reset, verification email) but not the sign in link.

Any idea of a solution to this ?

Comment: Is your redirectUrl whitelisted in your Firebase console's Authorized Domains under Authentication? I'm fighting the same issue and trying to figure it out.

Comment: FYI: I can't even get the link sent to an email address IN the white listed domain... :(